# Remove or excerpt text of message notification in Buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have a similar issue as this one: [How to edit the registration email sent by buddypress for activating users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016305/how-to-edit-the-registration-email-sent-by-buddypress-for-activating-users)

In Buddypress if a user sends a "private message" to an other user, the user will the notified via email with the **entire text of the message.**

How can I either remove or shorten/ excerpt the body of the message ?

This is the text that I mean:

Alexander sent you a new message:

Subject: hallo

**"hallo
43545345"** <- *This is the body which I want to remove/replace or excerpt*

To view and read your messages please log in and visit: http://www.mycolombianwife.com/members/alexandra/messages/

---

To disable these notifications, please log in and go to: http://www.mycolombianwife.com/members/alexandra/settings/notifications/

Answer (score 0):

Use the provided filter hook. 
Try this function in [bp-custom.php](https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/bp-custom-php/)

```
function user3461751_email_content( $email_content, $sender_name, $subject, $content, $message_link, $settings_link, $ud ) {
  $email_content = 'replacement text'; 
  return $email_content;
}
add_filter('messages_notification_new_message_message', 'user3461751_email_content', 10, 7 );
```